# Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<ShopDispatchTypes>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Error:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<ShopDispatchTypes>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(GetShops());
}, []);
```

I am trying to implement redux-thunk using Typescript. I have created simple shopping card app using react,typescript and redux-thunk but getting above issue.
Below is my code snippet’s. Feel free to ask if you need more info.

shops.actionTypes.ts

```
export const SHOP_LOAD_START = 'SHOP_LOAD_START';
export const SHOP_LOAD_SUCCESS = 'SHOP_LOAD_SUCCESS';
export const SHOP_LOAD_ERROR = 'SHOP_LOAD_ERROR';

export type Shop = {
 id: string;
 name: string;
};

export type ShopType = {
 shops: Shop[];
};

export interface ShopLoadStart {
 type: typeof SHOP_LOAD_START;
}

export interface ShopLoadError {
 type: typeof SHOP_LOAD_ERROR;
}

export interface ShopLoadSuccess {
 type: typeof SHOP_LOAD_SUCCESS;
 payload: ShopType;
}

export type ShopDispatchTypes = ShopLoadStart | ShopLoadError | ShopLoadSuccess;
```

shops.action.ts

```
export const GetShops = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch<ShopDispatchTypes>) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: SHOP_LOAD_START,
    });

    const res = await http.get('d9b45894-2549-4e34-9486-7668c2e000a0');

    dispatch({
      type: SHOP_LOAD_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: SHOP_LOAD_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

shops.reducer.ts

```
export interface IDefaultState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  shop?: ShopType;
}

export const defaultState: IDefaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
};

const shopsReducer = (
  state: IDefaultState = defaultState,
  action: ShopDispatchTypes
): IDefaultState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOP_LOAD_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case SHOP_LOAD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        shop: action.payload,
      };
    case SHOP_LOAD_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default shopsReducer;
```

store.ts

```
const Store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export default Store;
```

ShoppingCard.tsx

```
const ShoppingCard: React.FC<IShoppingCard> = (props: IShoppingCard) => {
  const { label } = props;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const shopsData = useSelector((state: RootStore) => state.shop);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetShops()); //Getting error here
  }, []);

}
```

If I am doing anything wrong please let me know. Spent several hours for that but didn't find any solution.

GitHub: [Source code link](https://github.com/tush241191/react-redux-thunk-demo)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that `const dispatch = useDispatch();` only knows about the basic `Dispatch` type from the `redux` core.  That `Dispatch` type does not know that thunks exist - it only accepts plain action objects.  So, when you try to dispatch a thunk, it (correctly) errors.

The fix is to follow our "Usage with TS" guidelines for correctly inferring an `AppDispatch` type from `store.dispatch`, and then defining pre-typed hooks that have the thunk types baked in:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start

Also, while it's not directly related to the question: the "hand-written" Redux patterns you're using are very outdated, and not how we want people using Redux today.  Instead, we now teach a set of "modern Redux" patterns that are much easier to learn and use - Redux Toolkit for logic + React-Redux hooks. Our official docs tutorials teach RTK+hooks as standard Redux today, but most other tutorials are very outdated.  See our official docs to learn how to use Redux Toolkit, which will drastically simplify the code you've got there:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: Now its working by referring above official doc.

Comment: This is a hack that should be fixed at the Redux level. The fact is you can pass a function to `dispatch`, so Redux types should allow you to do that. It's perfectly valid, especially given the prevalence of thunks in the community.

Comment: @AndyJessop: the core store, by itself, _does not_ let you pass in a function. That's why the core `Dispatch` type does not include that. The `thunk` middleware has always been a separate lib. Now, yes, it's certainly used in the vast majority of Redux apps, but there are also many folks who do _not_ use thunks (like folks who prefer sagas/observables). So, the types reflect reality here. On the other hand, RTK's `configureStore` sets up thunks by default,  _and_ does a better job of inferring any modifications to `dispatch` than `createStore` does - both why we want people using RTK.

Comment: I disagree. Redux _does_ allow you to pass in a function, because you can hijack the event before it hits the check.

The type should allow anything, but the dispatch handler itself in the Redux store should continue to check that it's the correct action shape.

Comment: That's exactly my point. **The base Redux store _does not_ allow that!** It immediately hits the `isPlainObject` check and throws. It's _only_ when you add middleware like `redux-thunk` that `store.dispatch` can accept a function, because the middleware intercepts it. Since `thunk` is a _separate_ library, the _base_ types accurately reflect exactly what that API can do And since React-Redux can't know ahead of time what _your_ store is configured as, `useDispatch` uses the base Redux lib `Dispatch` type. That's why we teach the `useAppDispatch` + inference pattern to match your app's usage.

Comment: @AndyJessop please do the experiment: create a store without any middleware and dispatch a function. It will give you [this error message](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/dac90dd887819b0abfec2c60de0ec2d4e6b4c77d/src/createStore.ts#L239-L245). The types of `redux` alone reflect that. If you add middleware, you have to accomodate to the typings of **your** setup with manual code.

Comment: I know it will give you that error message - that's what I said in my previous comment. The fact is that redux is designed so that when dispatch, it passes through the middleware first, and that middleware chain can take _any_ parameter type, as long as it _returns_ an action.

My suggestion is to allow any type to be passed to dispatch, but to throw the erorr if it exits the middleware chain as anything but an action.

This is how Redux is designed, it should be allowed by Redux's TS. FWIW, I maintain a separate Redux types package and monkey-patch the Redux `Store` type for this purpose.

Comment: @markerikson the base Redux store _does_ allow that, because it allows you to create middleware.

Comment: You're really missing the point here. **Middleware are not built into the base `createStore()` call by default, therefore the types do not allow you to pass anything that is not a plain action object**.  TS cannot know ahead of time that _you_ may have called `applyMiddleware(some, random, middleware, here)` in your particular app and that those middleware modify how `dispatch` will behave.  So just because modification is _possible_ does not mean that the base types can have any knowledge of that.

Comment: @Tusharkharat can you send us your changed code after following the documents? I am currently having the same issue and am quite confused after reading the docs.

Comment: @thegreenedition : Please see our TS setup page at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start - follow the patterns shown there and this will work .

Comment: @thegreenedition you can find working example here https://github.com/tush241191/react-redux-example