# error dispatching a function that dispatches an action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to dispatch a tryAutoLogin function. That tryAutoLogin function checks is AsyncStorage if there is data, and updates the auth state using the setCredentials action. I'm calling the function like this:

```
const autoLoginAndInitialize = async () => {
  dispatch(tryAutoLogin());
  updateDeviceId();
};
```

and the tryAutoLogin function looks like this:

```
export const tryAutoLogin = () => async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  try {
    const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");

    if (userData) {
      const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(userData);
      console.log("parsed data", parsedUserData);
      dispatch(auth.actions.setCredentials({ ...parsedUserData }));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error while trying to auto-login:", err);
  }
};
```

However, I'm getting a red underline in the `tryAutoLogin()` after the dispatch, with the following error:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: AppDispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
```

I tried changing the dispatch type to several different types but I haven't been successful. This structure was working OK in plain JS, but when changing to TS is giving this error. Any clue of what's wrong?

Edit:

My store.ts configuration looks like this:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
  devTools: true,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript), I'm using a custom useDispatch and useSelector in a separate hooks file:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../redux/rootReducer";
import { AppDispatch } from "../redux/store";

type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Then, the complete snippet of where I'm calling the tryAutoLogin() function is this one:

```
const AppNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const permissionStatus = useAppSelector(
    notificationSelectors.selectPermissionStatus
  );
  const expoPushToken = useAppSelector(notificationSelectors.selectExpoPushToken);
  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDeviceId = async () => {
      await saveDeviceCredentials();
      initializeApp(dispatch, permissionStatus, expoPushToken);
    };

    const autoLoginAndInitialize = async () => {
      dispatch(tryAutoLogin());
      updateDeviceId();
    };

    autoLoginAndInitialize();
```

Again, the error regarding the `dispatch(tryAutoLogin());` is the following:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: AppDispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
(alias) tryAutoLogin(): (dispatch: any) => Promise<void>
import tryAutoLogin
```

Edit 2:

Using `createAsyncThunk` in the tryAutoLogin() function instead leads to this new error:

```
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
```

having trouble using dispatch() in other parts of my app, considering the problem to be exclusively from dispatch?

this is the tryAutoLogin function with createAsyncThunk:

```
export const tryAutoLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/tryAutoLogin",
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");

      if (userData) {
        const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(userData);
        console.log("parsed data", parsedUserData);
        dispatch(auth.actions.setCredentials({ ...parsedUserData }));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error while trying to auto-login:", err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72399130/13488990) answer your question?

Comment: saw that answer before but couldn't apply anything successful to my case yet

Comment: Can you [edit] to share a more complete [mcve] how the store is instantiated and configured, and what is exported for use by the app?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the question with more information, hopefully is enough to give an idea.

Comment: I don't see notice anything overtly wrong with the store and `AppDispatch`. I think this might be an issue with using Redux-toolkit and what is effectively a "legacy" thunk function. Have you tried [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) instead for the `tryAutoLogin` action?

Comment: Will try with `createAsyncThunk` and give feedback, thankyou

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the question, the error now changed to `Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.`

Am I wrong, or the dispatch shouldn't be 'AnyAction' anymore?

Comment: This appears to have only just shifted the same typescript issue a bit. I don't *think* you are incorrect in that the `dispatch` type should have been correctly inferred. What if instead of dispatching a `setCredentials` action you returned the credentials and used `tryAutoLogin.fulfilled` in a reducer case? This doesn't resolve the typescript issue but might get you around the issue for now.

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch has a 'generic' type that determines the type of dispatch. As you haven't provided any type to the dispatch it is in `AnyAction` type. Simply type the dispatch like so and you're good to go!:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>()

  const autoLoginAndInitialize = async () => {
    dispatch(tryAutoLogin())
    updateDeviceId()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying this but the result is exactly the same. 
`Argument of type '(dispatch: AppDispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.`

I'm importing the AppDispatch from my store like this:

`export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;`

i must be missing something...

Comment: Why are you putting `tryAutoLogin` inside dispatch? You can call it directly. It is not an action, action is an object that has a `type` and optionally `payload` field. Check out [this](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#designing-actions) page from redux documentary.

Comment: Are you asking yourself why you called `tryAutoLogin` in `dispatch` in your own answer? `tryAutoLogin` is an asynchronous action, so it returns a function instead of an action object, and works with middleware to be handled. See [fundamentals part 6: async logic](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) from the same Redux docs.

Comment: I haven't seen the edit 2, sorry about that.