# Error when using dispatch in Redux with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get data from the backend to the redux state, but when I try to transfer the creator's action to the dispatch, an error occurs:

**Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.**

```
(alias) fetchUsers(): (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => Promise<void>
import fetchUsers
```

The full code for each file is below.

UserList.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useTypedSelector } from "../hooks/useTypedSelector";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchUsers } from "../store/action-creator/user";

const UserList: React.FC = () => {
  const { users, error, loading } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers())
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <h1>{error}</h1>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <div>{user.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

user.ts:

```
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { UserAction, UserActionTypes } from "../../types/user";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchUsers = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS });
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      dispatch({
        type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch({
        type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ERROR,
        payload: "Error",
      });
    }
  };
};
```

types/user.ts:

```
export interface UserState {
  users: any[];
  loading: boolean;
  error: null | string;
}

export enum UserActionTypes {
  FETCH_USERS = "FETCH_USERS",
  FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_USERS_ERROR = "FETCH_USERS_ERROR",
}

interface FetchUserAction {
  type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS;
}

interface FetchUserSuccessAction {
  type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS;
  payload: any[];
}

interface FetchUserErrorAction {
  type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ERROR;
  payload: string;
}

export type UserAction =
  | FetchUserAction
  | FetchUserSuccessAction
  | FetchUserErrorAction;
```

Ready to provide information on other files if necessary.

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396293/argument-of-type-dispatch-dispatchshopdispatchtypes-promisevoid-is-n

Comment: @spender I read it, but I still don’t fully understand what the problem is :(

Comment: It looks like you're following the Redux Thunk pattern and trying to dispatch an async function. You might want to make sure you're following the [appropriate Redux patterns](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#introduction) and using the appropriate types. The pattern you're following is also a bit outdated, and you'd likely benefit from using @reduxjs/toolkit which includes the redux and redux-thunk libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<ShopDispatchTypes>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396293/argument-of-type-dispatch-dispatchshopdispatchtypes-promisevoid-is-n)